# 'comment_post' hook doesn't seem to work?

Tags: comments, hooks

This is driving me crazy - Does anyone know why this `'comment_post'` hook doesn't seem to work!? I've basically written an entire email notification plugin for it and it's failed on the first step.

After research I was sure this was the right hook as it is after the comment is saved to the database.

```
add_action( 'comment_post', 'test_notify' );

function test_notify($args , $args2) {
    //test
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
    $email = 'address@mail.com';
    $message = 'Args=' . $args . '<br>Args2=' . $args2;
    wp_mail( $email , 'test', $message, $headers);

    echo 'It works!';
    header("Location: /blog?thisworked=true");
}
```

When a comment is posted, the function is not triggered... at all? The `do_action` is on line 2095 of */wp-includes/comment.php*

```
do_action( 'comment_post', $comment_ID, $commentdata['comment_approved'] );
```

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know why this 'comment_post' hook doesn't seem to work!?

...

> When a comment is posted, the function is not triggered... at all?

The hook works. Try the following, it works:

```
add_action( 'comment_post', 'test_notify' );
function test_notify($args , $args2) {
    echo 'It works!'; 
    die;
}
```

As does this:

```
add_action( 'comment_post', 'test_notify' );
function test_notify($args , $args2) {
    echo 'It works!'; 
    header("Location: http://www.google.com");
    die;
}
```

This, in fact, works also but you are likely to get a 404:

```
add_action( 'comment_post', 'test_notify' );
function test_notify($args , $args2) {
    echo 'It works!'; 
    header("Location: /blog?thisworked=true");
    die;
}
```

You want to be using `site_url()` or `home_url()` probably:

```
add_action( 'comment_post', 'test_notify' );
function test_notify($args , $args2) {
    echo 'It works!'; 
    header('Location: '.home_url('/blog?thisworked=true'));
    die;
}
```

If those don't work, something is interfering and I don't know how to guess what.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - you are right - the hook does work. Putting the `echo` and `die` in echo all the variables back fine. It's only when I seem to add anything to do with `wp_mail` in this particular function that it stops working - is there any particular conflict between wp_mail and comments?

Comment: What, if anything, still does not work?

Comment: Sorry - accidental enter - have updated comment!

Comment: if I use the basic `mail(...` function it works fine... But ignores my SMTP routing and filters to add company branding etc as not attached to the `wp_mail` hooks

Comment: Ah... where/how are your "SMTP routing and filters" added?

Comment: Facepalm - was a stupid mistake in the email headers - didn't double check - will probably delete this question now as solution isn't at all relevant to the original title.

Comment: That's the trouble with debugging with an email in this instance... apologies and thank you so much for you help - it did actually really help in the end as it made me look in the right place!